# Need some intuition on Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$

Tags: measure-theory

Definition of Borel on $\mathbb R$ ($\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$) is that it's the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all open sets in $\mathbb R$.

OK, if I take some open set like $C = (0,1)$, by definition of $\sigma$-algebra the complement of $C$ must also be in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, so something like $(-\infty, 0] \cup [1, \infty)$ must be in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Clearly, any closed set is in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 2):

That is right you also have all closed sets and the countable union s of closed s sets what we call $F_{\sigma}$ and their complements which are call ed $ G_{\delta}$. However you can find Borel sets that aren't neither $ F_{\sigma}$ or $ G_{\delta}$.